# Securing connection between iOS app and Server

Tags: php, api, security

I'm currently in the process of strengthening the connection between my iOS app and my main server which hosts the API. There is no user authentication, it is an unsecured API

What is the best way to ensure people cannot intercept the requests between the iOS app and the server, extracting the headers and using my developed API themselves?

Comment: Quite simply https

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: You talk about a lack of authentication, but authentication doesn't prevent messages being intercepted during transmission. That's the job of _encryption_ - such as HTTPS. Authentication prevents unauthorised people from getting a successful response from your server when they make a request. What happens during the transmission of that request and response is not under the control of the server and has nothing to do with the authentication mechanism. So I wonder if the reason you haven't made any progress with this is because you're looking at the wrong solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to go is :

- Use HTTPS
- Add an API key, ie. a secret key that is obfuscated in your application, and sent in the authentication header, and the server checks it.